# VCA on 5 V power supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, voltage-controlled-amplifier

I've made a VCO and ADSR-generator with two Arduinos.
The VCO uses a DAC made with a resistor ladder, the ADSR-gen uses a 12-bit DAC. Everything is 5 V powered (USB charger of 1 A).

In my search for a VCA with op amps or transistors I only found VCAs with a double power supply (+/- 9 V or 12 V).

I'm trying hard to avoid such a setup because of simplicity.

I've tried this circuit, but gives a fairly distorted sound at lower levels of the envelope. I've tried to attenuate the VCO level and ADSR level overall, but to no avail.

[image]

I want to try these 2, but I am not sure I can use a LM358 op amp and BC337 transistor for this.

[image]

[image]

I'm not that great with calculating the correct resistor values with op amps and such.

My questions:

1. Because it's all low level (between 0-5 V) signals, is it possible
   to replace the op amps in the designs with LM358 with a 5 V power supply?
2. Is it ok to replace the BC549 with a BC337 (they are both NPN)?

Comment: Use PWM at above audio frequencies to gate your audio on and off. Duty cycle controls analogue amplitude.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'd like to keep it 'analog' on purpose :-)

Comment: Because you unjustifiably believe you might get a purer sound?

Comment: Again, thank your for your suggestion, but it does not relate to my questions.

Comment: A Jfet is usually used for a VCA, a transistor creates severe distortion but can be used for a muting switch. An LM358 is never used for audio because it produces crossover distortion, hiss and has poor high frequency slew rate.